# how to make a function retry after 429 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-status-code-429

i'm writing a programm to send multiple requests at a time but i fac erate limits errors how can i tell my function to retry after facing the 429 rate limits error,please help

this is the arrow function that calls the function in a loop :

```
data.Item.json.map(( id, index ) => setTimeout(()=>activityService.streamActivity(id),(5+index) * 6000))
```

and this is the streamActivity function:

```
    const streamActivity = (client) => (activityId) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.streams.activity(
            {
                id: activityId,
                types:
                    "time,heartrate,velocity_smooth,altitude,distance,latlng,cadence,watts,temp,moving,grade_smooth,average_speed",
                resolution: "high",
            },
            function (err, payload,next) {



                if (!err ) {






                    //save to dynamodb


                    var params = {
                        TableName: "streams",
                        Item: {
                            "id":activityId,
                            "json": payload,
                        }
                    };

                    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error("Unable to add movie",  ". Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                        } else {
                            console.log("PutItem succeeded:");
                        }
                    });


                } else {
                    
                
                 
                    reject(err);
                  
                }
            }
        );
    });
    

};
```

Comment: instead of rejecting the error, you can try incrementing a retry counter and calling the same function again

Comment: but how can i do that please? i am new to nodejs

Comment: https://dev.to/ycmjason/javascript-fetch-retry-upon-failure-3p6g
maybe this will help